# Azure Terraform: Datasource external produces weird error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-functions

**main.tf**

```
    terraform {
    required_version = ">= 1.5.5"

    required_providers {
        azurerm = {
        source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
        version = ">=3.69.0"
        }
    }
    }

    provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
    skip_provider_registration = true
    subscription_id            = "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx"

    }

    provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
    alias = "sub-fits-55070-dev-01"
    skip_provider_registration = true
    subscription_id            = "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx"
    }

    module "function_app_zis" {
    # checkov:skip=CKV_TF_1:Skipped "Ensure Terraform module sources use a commit hash"
    providers = {
        azurerm = azurerm.sub-fits-55070-dev-01
    }
    source                = "./.."
    resource_group_name   = "resourcegroup238495723985"
    function_app_name     = "myfunctionzis238495723985"
    location              = "westeurope"
    use_event_hub_trigger = false
    subnet_id             = "/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-network/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet-001/subnets/snet-002"
    zip_file_name         = "./functionapp/httptrigger/functionapp.zip"
    }

    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "this" {
    provider = azurerm.sub-fits-55070-dev-01
    name     = "rg-fixture"
    location = "westeurope"
    }

    data "external" "function_key" {
    program    = ["bash", "${path.module}/get_function_key.sh"]
    count      = module.function_app_zis.function_app_name != "" ? 1 : 0
    depends_on = [module.function_app_zis]
    }

    resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "example" {
    provider            = azurerm.sub-fits-55070-dev-01
    name                = "test1mag"
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
    short_name          = "auntmary"

    email_receiver {
        name                    = "test1email"
        email_address           = "blabla@test.com"
        use_common_alert_schema = true
    }
    azure_function_receiver {
        name                     = "test1function"
        function_app_resource_id = module.function_app_zis.function_app_id
        http_trigger_url         = "https://${module.function_app_zis.trigger_url}/api/httptrigger?code=${data.external.function_key[0].result["function_key"]}"
        function_name            = "httptrigger"
        use_common_alert_schema  = true
    }
    depends_on = [data.external.function_key]
    }

    output "function_app_http_trigger_url" {
    value = "https://${module.function_app_zis.trigger_url}/api/httptrigger?code=${data.external.function_key[0].result["function_key"]}"
    }
```

**get_function_key.sh**

```
    #!/bin/bash

    APP_NAME="func-myfunctionzis238495723985"
    RESOURCE_GROUP="resourcegroup238495723985"
    SUBSCRIPTION="sub-fits-55070-dev-01"
    FUNCTION_NAME="httptrigger"

    # Check if the function app is deployed
    for i in {1..30}; do
        FUNCTION_KEY=$(az functionapp function keys list --subscription $SUBSCRIPTION --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP --name $APP_NAME --function-name $FUNCTION_NAME --query default --output tsv)
        if [ "$FUNCTION_KEY" != "" ]; then
            echo "{\"function_key\": \"$FUNCTION_KEY\"}"
            break
        fi
    done
```

Debug Output

Output 1st run:

```
    Error: Unexpected External Program Results
    │
    │ with data.external.function_key[0],
    │ on main.tf line 138, in data "external" "function_key":
    │ 138: program = ["bash", "${path.module}/get_function_key.sh"]
    │
    │ The data source received unexpected results after executing the program.
    │
    │ Program output must be a JSON encoded map of string keys and string values.
    │
    │ If the error is unclear, the output can be viewed by enabling Terraform's
    │ logging at TRACE level. Terraform documentation on logging:
    │ https://www.terraform.io/internals/debugging
    │
    │ Program: /usr/bin/bash
    │ Result Error: unexpected end of JSON input
```

Output 2nd run:

```
    Error: Unexpected External Program Results
    │
    │ with data.external.function_key[0],
    │ on main.tf line 138, in data "external" "function_key":
    │ 138: program = ["bash", "${path.module}/get_function_key.sh"]
    │
    │ The data source received unexpected results after executing the program.
    │
    │ Program output must be a JSON encoded map of string keys and string values.
    │
    │ If the error is unclear, the output can be viewed by enabling Terraform's
    │ logging at TRACE level. Terraform documentation on logging:
    │ https://www.terraform.io/internals/debugging
    │
    │ Program: /usr/bin/bash
    │ Result Error: invalid character '{' after top-level value
```

Output 3rd run: no errors

I am deploying a function app in Azure via Azure DevOps / terraform.

As the resource azurerm_linux_function_app has no output for the function key of the function, which is needed in the action group, because otherwise the function is not triggered via the action group, I have to use a trick to get the function key into the action group.

As you can see I try to get the function key with an az query and use this output to get it delivered in the action group.

When I am running this, in the 1st run I am getting the output shown above, which indicates to me that there is no JSON content returned.

In a second run, I added two lines to the shell script:

```
    az login --service-principal -u ... -p ... --tenant ...
    az account set --subscription "sub-fits-55070-dev-01"
```

When I am running this, I get the error message shown above in run 2. This indicates to me, that there **is an output**, but terraform cannot handle this output properly.

In the third run, I am changing the shell script back to what it was in run 1, which means delete the two lines again that I have added in run 2.

Now, the third run is giving me the correct output and creates the action group.

This behavior is weird, because in the third run I am running exactly the same files that I had already used in run 1. But without the az login command in between, it does not work.

What is wrong here?

Apart from that **is there another way to get the function key as an output except the one I am using?**

Comment: May i know if you are using self-hosted agent or Microsoft agent? as it should need az login to get the function app key(your run 2).

Comment: may i know if there's any update? does the error persist or not happen any more?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with how you're returning the JSON payload in your bash loop. (You need to return it as a single JSON object, not multiple ones). If you simplify the return from get_function_key.sh you can replicate this... if we change that script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "{\"function_key\": \"BATMAN\"}"
echo "{\"function_key2\": \"BATMAN\"}"
```

The script output would look like this:

```
#sh get_function_key.sh
{"function_key": "BATMAN"}
{"function_key2": "BATMAN"}
```

This returns the same error message you're seeing:

```
│   on main.tf line 2, in data "external" "function_key":
│    2:     program    = ["bash", "get_function_key.sh"]
│ 
│ The data source received unexpected results after executing the program.
│ 
│ Program output must be a JSON encoded map of string keys and string values.
│ 
│ If the error is unclear, the output can be viewed by enabling Terraform's logging at TRACE level. Terraform documentation on logging:
│ https://www.terraform.io/internals/debugging
```

If you change your script to alter how you return that JSON data, for instance like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "{\"function_key1\": \"BATMAN\", \"function_key2\": \"ROBIN\"}"
```

Which outputs like this:

```
sh get_function_key.sh 
{"function_key1": "BATMAN", "function_key2": "ROBIN"}
```

Terraform is perfectly happy with your returned payload and you can leverage it. So modify how you build the return JSON object in the script - don't return multiples as you are now, build a single object.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which actually doesn't really help me because there is only 1 record needed as I only have 1 function key which is returned....

Comment: Run get_function_key.sh by hand and check the output (and share if possible). 

Your other potential here is the value for FUNCTION_KEY needs to be escaped. Also, it may be beneficial to return a JSON object regardless of if FUNCTION_KEY has a result or not.

Comment: The output is something like {"function_key": "abcdefgandsoon"}. In fact, the last hint is a good idea. I will test that. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi Matthew, yes, I tested that with the empty JSON. That worked, but if I do it like that, I get no function key back. The main issue still is, why the function key if given back only with my complicated procedure and if there is another way of getting it except the datasource idea.

Comment: In fact, giving back an empty JSON resolves the issue in run #1. But the basic problem why there are 3 runs needed to retrieve the key is still open.